# Is there a way to get rid of blue highlighting on questions?

Tags: support, tags

When you participate heavily in a tag,the questions on the main page with that tag are highlighted in blue.

[image: Blue highlighted questions]

**Is there a way to stop this behavior for a specific tag?** This problem arose as part of the Futurama Storm earlier today; since I viewed/edited/voted on so many [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) questions, the system classified it as a "frequented" tag. I assume blocking the tag would work, but I'd like to still see and help out with the questions. I just would prefer it if only tags that I actually possess expertise in were highlighted. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a site setting that disables the Frequent Tags feature.  However, there are several workarounds.  [The first](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/is-there-any-way-to-disable-frequent-tag-highlighting) is to just use the tag favoriting/ignoring feature in any capacity.  You can favorite or ignore a non-existant tag like [q-bert](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/q-bert), and you'll no longer have the 'Frequent tags' feature doing anything.

Alternatively, with some user CSS, you can un-blue them:

```
.tagged-interesting {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

---

March 19, 2013 edit:

[As of last June](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138187/158781), the frequented tags are no longer automatically highlighted.

Comment: The favorite/unfavorite trick worked fine.

Comment: I feel a sudden urge to ask a [tag:q-bert] question...

Answer (score -2):

The questions that are marked in blue are the ones you've marked as favorites (through the “Favorite Tags” box on the front page, or by clicking on the star at the top left of the box that appears when you hover on a tag so that it becomes yellow). So to control which tags appear in blue, pick your favorite tags manually.

If you have no favorite tag at all, the system chooses some for you based on what you've been visiting. If you don't want any blue questions, then as Keen already suggested, declare a non-existant tag like [no-blue-highlighting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-blue-highlighting) as favorite.

Answer (score -2):

If you have set [futurama] as a favourite tag, you can change that the following way.  Go to the Science Fiction and Fantasy site (not on meta), click on your username on the top of the page to go to your profile page, there click on the "prefs" link to go to your preferences page.  You should have your favorite tags listed there, and next to each tag, there's an × sign that you can click to remove that tag from your favorites.